# Getting Apache Version Using PHP Alternative

Tags: php, linux, apache

Is there an alternative way to get my Apache version without using the below code?

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE']; ?>
```

Returns "Apache".

```
<?php echo apache_get_version(); ?>
```

Returns "Fatal error: Call to undefined function apache_get_version()".

Note: I am using a Linux server with PHP v5.3.1, and anything returned with a linux-only command via the shell using exec() or shell_exec() would be acceptable. I just want to get it detecting the version of Apache for Linux at least.

Comment: `exec` with `httpd -v` or try `curl -I localhost` and parse that

Comment: Tried both but they don't return anything.

Comment: Erk, given the SERVER_SOFTWARE environment variable, my previous comment was indeed a dumb question. Output of [php_sapi_name()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) could be interesting to see, though.

Comment: The output from php_sapi_name() is "cgi-fcgi".

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`apache_get_version()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.apache-get-version.php)?

Answer (score 0):

you say using exec is fine ?

exec("apache2 -v") will give the output similar to

```
Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Nov 30 2012 08:33:45
```

using your first command would be best and just makiing apache expose itself a little more

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#ServerTokens

Change the .htaccess or the httpd.conf file to the token you want

Comment: It's not returning anything either. I also cannot configure ServerTokens from .htaccess and I do not have access to the httpd.conf file.

Comment: Note: ServerTokens may only be set in the server config (httpd.conf), not in .htaccess.